# How do I set mmqgis create grid options?

Tags: qgis, mmqgis, hexagonal-grid

I am having a puzzle about using mmqgis create vector layer option. I want to use UTM CSR[image: This are my options:]

this are my options. I want a grid of 20,000 meters in the east and north axis. Nevertheless i have an error screen stating: "invalid width/height 6.0/6.0". As I understand my settings I should have 6 lines separated by 20,000 meters
Am I understanding this in the wrong way? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without checking, I would interpret to options as follows:

- left x: min x
- width: width of the complete grid, therefore ... min x + width = max x
- h spacing: width of one cell

same for the second dimension

Comment: Yes! That was what I was looking to understand! Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error too.  The problem is is that the `Width` is less than the `H Spacing` you should just lower the `H Spacing` and the `V Spacing` will update automatically.

you can see the error in the source [here](http://sextante.googlecode.com/svn-history/r181/trunk/soft/bindings/qgis-plugin/src/sextante/mmqgis/sextante_mmqgis_library.py):

search for `Invalid width / height`

Comment: also here is the documentation http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with setting up the V and H spacing for hexagons. The dialogue box in mmqgis is less than helpful. What exactly does V spacing mean? What if I want to specify an area for each hexbin? What if I want to specify a side length? What does a V spacing of 1000 units mean in area?

I made a simple Python script (and an accompanying graphic) to help users with this problem. The issue is that the parameters are used to create the *bounding* of the hexagons, rather than any one hexagon itself.

Copy and paste this into a text file called `get_params.py`, then open console/command line and change the directory to where the file is and run `» python get_params.py`.

```
from math import sqrt

# Passes a desired area (in acres) and returns a dictionary of mmqgis v- and h-spacing parameters
def getParamsFromArea(target_area_ac):
  target_area_ft = 43560 * target_area_ac
  target_side_length = sqrt( target_area_ft / (3 * sqrt(3) / 2) )
  bounding_side_length = target_side_length * sqrt(3)
  bounding_incircle_radius = 3 * target_side_length / 2
  params = {'h-spacing': bounding_incircle_radius, 'v-spacing': bounding_side_length}
  print("""A target hexbin of {} acres yields a side 
  length of {:.4f} feet and is {} sq.ft. in area""".format(target_area_ac, target_side_length, target_area_ft))
  for k, v in params.iteritems():
    print("{}: {:10.8f} feet".format(k, v))
  for k, v in params.iteritems():
    print("{}: {:10.8f} meters".format(k, v * 0.3048))
  return params

# Passes a desired side length (in feet) and returns a dictionary of mmqgis v- and h-spacing parameters
def getParamsFromLength(target_side_length):
  target_area_ft = ( target_side_length * target_side_length ) * ( (3 * sqrt(3) ) / 2 )
  target_area_ac = target_area_ft * 2.29568e-5
  bounding_side_length = target_side_length * sqrt(3)
  bounding_incircle_radius = 3 * target_side_length / 2
  params = {'h-spacing': bounding_incircle_radius, 'v-spacing': bounding_side_length}
  print("A target hexbin with side length {} feet yields an area of {:.2f} acres and {} sq.ft. in area".format(target_side_length, target_area_ac, target_area_ft))
  for k, v in params.iteritems():
    print("{}: {:10.8f} feet".format(k, v))
  for k, v in params.iteritems():
    print("{}: {:10.8f} meters".format(k, v * 0.3048))
  return params

# Passes the mmqgis dialogue parameter 'V spacing' and prints the resulting side length and area
def translateVsp(v_spacing):
  bounding_side_length = v_spacing
  target_side_length = bounding_side_length / sqrt(3)
  target_area_ft = ( target_side_length * target_side_length ) * ( (3 * sqrt(3) ) / 2 )
  target_area_ac = target_area_ft * 2.29568e-5
  print("A V spacing of {} units yields a side length of {} units and an area of {} units squared.".format(v_spacing, target_side_length, target_area_ft))

# Get user input
mode = raw_input("Do you want to get parameters or translate V spacing? ('p' or 't'): ")
if mode == 't':
  v = input("Enter the V spacing from mmqgis input dialogue: ")
  translateVsp(v)
elif mode == 'p':
  calc_type = raw_input("Do you want to get parameters from a side length or an area? ('l' or 'a'): ")
  if calc_type == 'a':
    a = input("Enter the number of acres for the hexbin: ")
    getParamsFromArea(a)
  elif calc_type == 'l':
    l = input("Enter the side length for the hexbin: ")
    getParamsFromLength(l)
  else:
    print("Error: enter 'l' or 'a' (without quotes) when prompted.")
else:
  print("Error: enter 'p' or 't' (without quotes) when prompted to select a calculation mode.")
```

[image: explanation of mmqgis grid overlay for hexbins]