# Creating fishnet grid Shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

How do I create a fishnet shapefile using QGIS?

The equivalent task of "Create Fishnet" in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Look at the Processing Toolbox and you may choose many algorithms without the need of a plugin

[image]

Answer (score 25):

You don't need a plugin, just use a geoalgorithm from the toolbox:

```
Vector > Research Tools > Create Grid...
```

In QGIS 2.10 this is called 'Create Graticule'

Answer (score 12):

Vector grid creation has been incorporated in QGIS for a long time:

```
Vector -> Research Tools -> Vector Grid
```

Note that the default grid spacing of `0.0001000000` units of the layer CRS is too small in most cases.

You might want to use `Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Densify Geometries` afterwards if you need to reproject the grid to another CRS where the lines should appear bended.

Answer (score 6):

In QGIS 3.4, in the Processing toolbox, look for `SAGA` >> `Vector general` >> `Create polygons graticule`

Answer (score 4):

In QGIS 3.16. Hannover.

1. Install the plugin MMQGIS.
2. Once MMQGIS shows up at the upper toolbar, select:

   `MMQGIS >> Create >> Create Grid Layer`
3. When the window shows up, remember to select the Geometry type "Rectangle" and that the layer units are in meters with the appropriate projected CRS (for further information on this issue read this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54926/mmqgis-how-to-make-grid-layer-in-meters-not-degrees)). This is an example:
   [image: Grid Window]

Comment: This is the only usable one I found. All the rest don't work anymore.