# Getting equidistant regions from a map with qgis

Tags: qgis

I'm builing a webapp for which I need to get some GIS work. I have a csv file containing data from a city, split by district, with the following relevant elements:

```
lat, long, geoJson(multipolygon for each district)
```

What I'd like to do is to split the map into X equidistant regions. I need to do this in order to "rank" each region according to different properties.

I'm using qgis and I tried finding a solution with no success, I'm a begginer in GIS but I know how to program, just in case there's code involved in some solution.

Answer (score 1):

To create a grid layer that represents equidistant regions you may use (in QGIS v2.12):

- `Vector -> Research Tools -> Vector Grid`
- or [How to create a fishnet grid Shapefile in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123444/create-fishnet-grid-in-qgis)

If you want to join other vector data layer attribute info to grid layer you may use:

- `Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Join Attributes by Location`

Comment: I tried following the steps but I didn't find a field on which I could select the amount of subregions to get. I'd like to split each regions in five subregions initially.