# Correlate two different zone system records

Tags: qgis, postgis, algorithm

I am working with two data sets from different sources that represent the same phenomena and have a challenging point.

Both data sets represent demographic attributes of the population [ `person id`, `age`, `gender`, `income`, ... ] and records are matched to the zone number with no specific location. So I can only map them to the center of the zone.

My question is, what algorithm, method, technique is suitable to find a common grid system for both zones for comparison? They should represent a high correlation as they are for the same population.

I use PostGIS, QGIS, Python and Java

[image: two zone systems overlaid]

Answer (score -1):

Probably you can divide both the datasets to smaller grids and then run comparative analysis.

For making grids in QGIS refer to answer of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123444/creating-fishnet-grid-shapefile-in-qgis).

For splitting them you can use [fishnet in ArcGIS](http://giscourse.com/index.php/blog-giscourse/129-creating-a-fishnet-using-arcgis-10).

Comment: Thank you for the replay, I think the problem is that the whole records are only in each zone center. so, only the grid that intersect with the center of the zone will have 100 % of the zone records which which will lead to very low correlation

Comment: but, one Idea I got from you comment is to reallocate or geo-smooth the point distribution in each zone based on some probability distribution, then continue the grid comparative analysis