# Creating 1km square grid

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I am trying to make a 1km square grid using QGIS 2.18.26.

I am using EPSG:4326. I need it to be exactly 1km square because that's how the variable data has been collected.

I am struggling to get the grid to be exactly 1km square, I have attempted using Vector Create Grid, and MMQGIS create grid layer, but I am unsure how to set the grid units to 1km square.

[image: My best attempt, Grid has been set to the extent of the multicoloured points, preferably the grid would have 1 multicoloured point per square]

Comment: Change the CRS of the project to a shape preserving projection, generate the fishnet in that CRS.  Project the resulting data back to EPSG4326 https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123444/creating-fishnet-grid-shapefile-in-qgis

Comment: Do you need to work with this grid, or could you use the one froms `decorations`? Also, why does your basemap has to use 4326?

Comment: It might be useful to densify the grid before reprojecting back to EPSG:4326, because projected straight lines become bended in a latlon CRS.

Comment: I always understood that 1 degree changes length with latitude so trying to create a regular 1Km grid in WGS84 would be impossible. The dataset needs to be projected to a local coordinate system in metre units to make a regular 1km grid?

Comment: @Erik the basemap doesn't have to be 4326 I was advised to use it. I have 0 experience with GIS so any tips would be useful. I need to make a grid which I can group data by for GAM analysis.

Comment: @AndreJ how would I densify the grid? Sorry if that's a silly question.

Comment: If you create the grid with `Vector -> Research Tools -> Vector Grid`, just run `Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Densify geometries` on the output layer with 49 or 99 additional vertices afterwards. And use a projected CRS like UTM.

Comment: 1 km =0.00899928