# Same projections but different extents

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, extents

I have one shapefile and one delimited file and though they are projected on the same coordinate system WGS 84, they dont overlap all the way because their extents are different.

The extent of the delimited file is 0.00,-90.00 : 356.25,90.00
and shapefile is -180.00,-55.98 : 180.00,83.65

Most of the other delimited files and shapefiles I would be using also have the same extent as the shapefile. Is there anyway I can get the first delimited file to overlap? [image]

Comment: Totally not understanding what you're doing. You can't "join" points and polygons, and where did you come up that "356.25" extent?

Comment: Your delimited data isn't in WGS84 - EPSG 4326. Hence the data doesn't overlap. There should be a CRS using degrees and ranging from 0 to 360, instead of -180 to 180. Use that one to load your delimited data.

Comment: Thanks @Erik , I think that's the problem. I am not very familiar with coordinate systems - which one would project it to 0 to 360?

Comment: does the 0-360 data have any attributes? If not and you just need a graticule/grid/fishnet, see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123444/creating-fishnet-grid-shapefile-in-qgis) for some tools that can build one.

Comment: @mkennedy I tried to do that but the grids also stay 0-360.

Comment: what is a "delimited file"? Can you share your data? Can you tell us a bit more what did you do to get the image you posted? How did you create the points? What CRS do these two layers have? A lot of open questions you should answer to get a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the layer source is a CSV text file, export it to a vector format (e.g., GeoPackage).

Once the new layer is loaded, run the **Convert format** tool. It's in the  *Vector conversion* group of the Processing Toolbox.

In the dialog, just include the following line in the *Aditional creation options*, under the *Advanced Parameters* group:

`-s_srs "+proj=latlon +datum=WGS84 +lon_wrap=180" -t_srs "EPSG:4326"`

Just run the tool and the new layer must be wraped around the 0 degrees longitude.

---

We are designating a new origin coordinate system for a vector conversion.
Vector conversion is done by the [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) command, in this case run from QGIS.
The origin coordinate system is being defined from a proj string that includes the [+lon_wrap](https://proj.org/usage/projections.html#longitude-wrapping) parameter to indicate that the original data is written around the 180 degrees meridian.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly.