# Best fit/worse fit using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

[image]

I've added an image

The Blue area is the SPA area for the South Pennines, the red dot is a nesting bird, the 10km purple circle is the buffer zone of where another nest will not be allowed to reside.

I would like to work out and map the best fit for the nests (red dots) inside the blue area without the 10KM buffer zones overlapping (it doesn't matter if the buffer zones are outside the SPA).

Does that make sense to anyone? can it be done, can I then reverse this to see the worst case senario?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: To get this re-opened, please expand on what you want to do. What kind of scenario? What constitutes best and worst?

Comment: Please reformulate the question so everybody understands it. Try to make a croquis of what you intend to do, or maybe an example on the internet.

Comment: Try the MMQGIS grid tool with Hexagons, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41673/how-do-i-set-mmqgis-create-grid-options